# Reduzir tamanho de jar em Projeto Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Estou gerando um jar a partir de um projeto Maven e o tamanho esta absurdamente alto.

Quais medidas posso tomar para reduzir o tamanho deste jar?

Comment: Talvez o mais importante é verificar se todas as libs anexas ao jar são realmente necessárias, pois se tem lib que não é usada, ela pode ser removida, pois só está "pesando" seu jar.

Comment: Tenho adicionado o Scope de cada lib. É um jar executável, sendo que adicioneis umas 3 libs que uso no projeto. A forma de verificação que voce se refere é o Scope nas configurações do pom.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é criar o jar sem as dependências. O jar conterá somente as classes do projeto e ficará bastante reduzido. Nesse caso, você vai precisar colocar os jars que o projeto precisa em algum lugar e adicionar esses jars no classpath do projeto.

O seu pom.xml ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>testes.testes.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>poi-ooxml-3.14.jar poi-3.14.jar</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Dessa forma, o jar será criado sem as dependências.
o trecho com o `<Class-Path>` será adicionado no arquivo MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: Excelente vou dar uma olhada sobre.

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se alguma dependência adicionada no seu POM.XML pode ser removida.

Além disso, muitas vezes uma dependência depende de várias outras libs. Se vc tem certeza que alguma delas não está em uso vc pode removê-la usando

Ex:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>br.com.teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>artefato-teste</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>br.com.teste</groupId>
        <artifactId>sub-artefato-teste</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Além de seguir o conselho dos colegas e rever dependências e dependências transitivas, existem ferramentas que podem te ajudar.

Uma primeira maneira de reduzir o tamanho do Jar é compactar utilizando [Pac200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack200). Você pode fazer isso com o Maven utilizando o plugin [Maven Pack200 Plugin](https://github.com/batkinson/Maven-Pack200-Plugin).

Outra maneira é utilizar um plugin como o [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) capaz de criar um Uber Jar minificado (i.e., que empacote apenas classes realmente utilizadas pela aplicação) ou ainda algo como o [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) que além de remover classes não utilizadas também diminui, "ofusca" e otimiza o código.

Todas essas ferramentas tem suas limitações. Por exemplo, parte dos servidores de aplicação não funcionam com jars compactados com pac200. Minificadores e otimizadores também podem ser perigosos, eles não conseguem detectar classes carregadas por reflexão e geralmente requerem um certo esforço de configuração manual (excluir classes do processo de minificação) quando utilizados com frameworks e bibliotecas mais complexas. Também não é incomum ter problemas ao utilizar um ofuscador com novas versões do Java (geralmente leva um tempo até o ProGuard ser atualizado).